# How to place content of a div inside link on php while loop

Tags: php, ajax

Please I'm new to coding and I have a project i am working on.

I have a php while loop code that diplay 5 posts

I also have a jQuery code to display modal for the while loop with post url

The problem I'm face here is that the displayed url is inside a div

`<p id="url"></p>` this show the url

I want to add it as url.

I have tried `<a href='<p id="url"></p>'> Click to view</a>`

But the link will not show

I have tried echo it still not showing.

I have been on this for two days now

The modal that display the content is outside the while loop and working

I need help

My ajax code

```
<script>

    function showModal(id)
    {
        $("#url").text($("#url_"+id).text());
    
    }

</script>
```

Php loop code

```
    `<?php 
                foreach ($posts as $key => $result) {   ?>      
     <div href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onClick="showModal(<?php echo $id ;  ?>)" class="side-icon share-btn">
              <i class="fa fa-share share-icon"></i> View link
                       <?php } ?>

      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;margin:0;width:100%;">
<div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
    <center><h4>Share with friends</h4></center>
        <?php $t='<p id="name"></p>';
        $t1?>
    <a href="<? $t?>">. Click to view</a>
            </div>
```

`

The id containers the url from MySQL table
The issue I'm facing is that, `<p id="url"></p>` is just showing www. example.com as plain test on user view but can't make it work as link to click

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow barry. have you visited our [tour] and have you learn on [ask]? if not, please do so. for your information `<a href='<p id="url"></p>'>` is not a valid html.. i'm not sure what you want to achieve. i believe you need to check on how to write [mcve] too.

Comment: ID attributes **must** be unique so even if the latter piece of HTML were valid you could not repeat the same ID. You **do not** need to use ID attributes at all to accomplish your goals - you can use the `event` triggered by the click to find the correct DOM node and build from there

Comment: Please add some of the rendered HTML or the PHP loop that generates the HTML - it is not clear what you mean just with small fragments of html

Comment: What i want is to make the url clickable but it show nothing inside the href  but showing url on user view

Comment: @BarryClinton, are you trying to get the `url` of each post to be added into a `href` in the modal using javascript?

Comment: Yes please, I want it to be added

Comment: Where is the content to be added within the `modal`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius this is the content, I want to make a link  <?php $t='<p id="name"></p>';
    ?>
<a href="<? $t?>">. Click to view</a>
        </div>

Comment: is that fragment of PHP within the modal?

Comment: @BarryClinton umm, i dont think we are on the same page. please dont panic, take a break (or a refreshing drink at least - fresh water will do). there are some missing component in this question: 1) how does the php loop looked like; 2) the modal to put the link in (at which part?); 3) are you using jquery and bootstrap? - your modal looked like a fragment of [tag:twitter-bootstrap] modal.

Comment: @BagusTesa I have added the php loop code

Comment: `href` is **not** a valid attribute for a `div` element

Comment: I understand but i don't know how to go over it to get div to be url because the id contains the url

Comment: `" i don't know how to go over it to get div to be url because the id contains the url"` - ? not sure I follow but I made a change below that takes the text content of the display (paragraph elements) and uses that URL as the hyperlink `href` attribute.

Comment: The issue I'm face is that, <p id="url"></p> is just show www. example.com as plain test on user view but can't make it work as link

Answer (score 1):

A hyperlink `a` is not necessary to invoke the modal dialog - most DOM elements can invoke whatever function you like. You assign an event listener either to all nodes of interest or a delegated listener bound to a common parent element. The snippet below might be of use?

```js
// add delegated listener on the containing node that has the content that is to be clicked
// by the user to invoke the modal dialog.

document.querySelector('div.urls').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Only process nodes that are not the specified target itself. ie: it's children
  if (e.target != e.currentTarget) {
    let modal=document.getElementById('myModal');


    // add the content from the clicked node to the modal somewhere
    let link = modal.querySelector('a[data-id="modal-target"]');
        link.setAttribute('href', e.target.textContent);
        link.innerHTML = 'Click to view';
  }
});
```

```css
.url:hover {
  color: red
}
.url {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class='urls'>
  <p class='url'>https://www.example.com</p>
  <p class='url'>https://www.banana.com</p>
  <p class='url'>https://www.bogus.org</p>
</div>



<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;margin:0;width:100%;">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"></div>
      
      <a data-id='modal-target'></a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't solve my issue

Comment: OK - I'll admit that I guessed what you were trying to do as it is not exactly clear so far.  Are you wanting to take the displayed URL (non-hyperlinked) and use that within the modal as the actual HREF for a hyperlink also within the modal?

Comment: Yes that is what i want, the id from MySQL containers the url to display but I can't get it to work on the Modal for someone to click